# #IF Silverlight for interfaces

Tags: .net, silverlight, multi-targeting

I have a multitargeted domain project (SL and .Net 4.0) and with problem with Color and so on I was using #if SILVERLIGHT constructs, but now I need to have for a SL project using my domain project few classes implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo which is not implemented on .Net 4.0 site and I will never use it.

I would be gratefull for advice how to make something like this

```
public class MyDomainClass: INotifyPropertyChanged, #IF Silverlight INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use the partial keyword in silverlight:

```
public partial class MyDomainClass: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
 // implement everything on INotifyPropertChanged 
}


#IF Silverlight 
public partial class MyDomainClass:INotifyDataErrorInfo 
{
     // implement everything on INotifyDataErrorInfo 
     // if needed using the stuff from the 'shared' class
}
#ENDIF
```